# Sending variables to other function

Tags: php

With this code, I'm getting an error:

**Missing argument 1 for PurchaseController::postPurchase(), called in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ec/app/controllers/PurchaseController.php on line 44 and defined**

```
public $input;
public $id;


    public function getPurchase()
    {
        return View::make('general.purchase');
    }

    public function getCheckout()
    {
        return View::make('general.checkout');
    }

    public function getItemView($id)
    {
        if (isset($id)) {
            $this->id = $id;
            return View::make('general.purchase')
                    ->with('item', Catagory::where('id', '=', $id)->firstOrFail());

        } else {
            return App::abort(404);
        }
    }

    public function postPurchaseCheck($id)
    {
        $input = Input::all();
        $this->input = $input;

        if (Input::get('buy')) {
           return $this->postPurchase();
        }
        elseif (Input::get('cart')) {
           return $this->postAddCart();
        }

    }

    public function postPurchase($id)
    {
        echo $id;
    }
```

And here is my controller:

```
        Route::post('/purchase/{id}', array(
                        'as'=>'purchase-post',
                        'uses'=>'PurchaseController@postPurchaseCheck'
                ));
```

And after posting to the function postPurchase() i get the following url:

**purchase/%7Bid%7D**

Comment: Why would you expect `$this->id` to be available from a previous request? Every request creates a new instance of Laravel... (or PHP in general), variable assignment will never persist.

Comment: I'm new to laravel and PHP so I'm not really sure what that means :(

Comment: It means that you ask Laravel for the view by going to the URL for `getItemView`. You return the view, Laravel sends to the browser. Instance of Laravel is now _terminated_. You fill in a form and post it to the URL for `postPurchase`. The previous instance of laravel has been terminated... nothing that was set in that instance is now available to your `postPurchase` method. To get your ID, you should send it as a URL param or in the POST data for your route.

Comment: That should be an answer tbh... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

In laymans terms: Your asking Laravel for the item view by going to the URL for `getItemView`. Laravel returns the compiled views HTML and sends to the browser. This instance of Laravel is now terminated. You fill in a form and post it to the URL for `postPurchase`.

As you see abouve, the previous instance of laravel has been terminated... nothing that was set in that instance is now available to your `postPurchase` method. To get your item ID, you should send it as a URL param or in the POST data for your route.

## Example

### Controller

```
class MyController extends BaseController {

    public function getItemView($id)
    {
        // Your code here
    }

    public function postPurchase($id)
    {
        // Your code here (notice id as param)
    }
}
```

### Routes

```
Route::get('item/{id}', 'MyController@getItem');

Route::post('purchase/{id}', 'MyController@postPurchase');
```

Now in your form, when you submit it you would need to make sure the url includes the id of the item that should be sent to the `postPurchase` method.

```
<form method="POST" action="/purchase/4">
    <!-- form HTML here -->
</form>
```

Hope that shows you what you need to be doing. You could, if you like send the id as a post variable by making it a hidden field in the form.

Comment: Thanks! I would really appreciate it if you could show me an example because I still am not sure how to do it

Comment: Added a quick example for you

Comment: I change the code and I'll edit the original question to show what I have now.